# remove package with broken pipe problem

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, dpkg, qupzilla

I installed qupzilla today to replace chrome (it was hogging WAY to much ram).
I liked it and I wanted to update it to the latest version using there repository but as I tried to update it an error popped up:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/qupzilla_1.8.6-1~trusty_amd64.deb 
(--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qupzilla/libPIM.so', which is also in package libqupzilla1 1.6.0-1  
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
/var/cache/apt/archives/qupzilla_1.8.6-1~trusty_amd64.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried `apt-get autoremove` and I tried `apt-get remove libqupzilla1`. It doesn't work and returns a broken pipe error.

So I started synaptic package manager and tried to remove libqupzilla1.
Unfortunately it wants to update qupzilla at the same time (so it starts by updating before removing) resulting in, yet again, the same error.

After that I tried to manually remove the file it tries to overwrite but unfortunately to no avail. The file is removed (backuped to a save location and then removed using `sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qupzilla/libPIM.so`) but it gives the same error.

Does anyone have a tip or hint I can use to first remove libqupzilla1 before updating qupzilla??
I'm fearing that I'll have to remove qupzilla just to remove this old lib package but if there is a way around it I would love to learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after some searching I managed to forcefully remove the libqupzilla1 package and update qupzilla to the latest release.
For future reference: I removed the package using the following code

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -P libqupzilla1
```

After that I installed the lastest version using

```
sudo apt-get install qupzilla
```